# Creating List partition to an already Existing Table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to Create a list partition Based on the column "REFRESH_FLAG_Y" which has only Y and N as its Values, Below is the Alter Table used to Create the partition

```
ALTER TABLE "EDW"."LABOR_SCHEDULE_DAY_F" MODIFY
PARTITION BY LIST ("REFRESH_FLAG") 
 (PARTITION "REFRESH_FLAG_Y"  VALUES ('Y') , 
 PARTITION "REFRESH_FLAG_N"  VALUES ('N')) ;
 COMMIT;
```

But Whenever I execute the code I get an Error message
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14400: inserted partition key does not map to any partition

Comment: 11g doesn't allow to partition non-partitioned table. You have to use [`DBMS_REDEFINITION`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_redefi.htm#ARPLS042)

Answer (score 2):

You did tag the question with Oracle 11g tag; do you really use it?

---

This is a 12c example; it *works* if everything is OK:

```
SQL> create table labor_schedule_day_f as
  2  select 1 id, 'Y' refresh_flag from dual union all
  3  select 2 id, 'N' refresh_flag from dual;

Table created.

SQL> alter table labor_schedule_Day_f modify
  2  partition by list (refresh_flag)
  3  (partition refresh_flag_y values ('Y'),
  4   partition refresh_flag_n values ('N')
  5  );

Table altered.
```

---

Error you reported means this:

```
SQL> drop table labor_schedule_day_f;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table labor_schedule_day_f as
  2  select 1 id, 'Y' refresh_flag from dual union all
  3  select 2 id, 'N' refresh_flag from dual;

Table created.
```

Insert a row whose `REFRESH_FLAG` isn't `Y` nor `N` (so it *violates* the rule you specified):

```
SQL> insert into labor_schedule_day_f values (3, 'X');

1 row created.
```

Using the same `ALTER TABLE` statement as previously:

```
SQL> alter table labor_schedule_Day_f modify
  2  partition by list (refresh_flag)
  3  (partition refresh_flag_y values ('Y'),
  4   partition refresh_flag_n values ('N')
  5  );
alter table labor_schedule_Day_f modify
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14400: inserted partition key does not map to any partition


SQL>
```

See? Error you got, which means that

> which has only Y and N as its Values

isn't true.

P.S. You'd get the same result even if `refresh_flag` was `NULL` for some rows.

Comment: The feature is available [since 12.2.0.1](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Changes-in-This-Release-for-Oracle-Database-SQL-Language-Reference.html#GUID-0B18172E-8876-40D0-84DE-53C2CE6436BD), to be precise, not for any 12c: *You can change a nonpartitioned table to a partitioned table.

See the new clause modify_to_partitioned of ALTER TABLE.*